# Pros and cons of configuring SSL certificate in webserver vs Kubernetes Ingress/OpenShift route level

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, openshift

Assume I have a Python application/JBoss application.
I can setup my SSL certificate at server level

For instance in Python 3 using `SimpleHTTPServer`:

```py
def main():
    key_file = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.fr/privkey.pem"
    cert_file = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.fr/fullchain.pem"
    port = 9443
    httpd = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', port), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,
                                   keyfile=key_file,
                                   certfile=cert_file, server_side=True)

    httpd.serve_forever()
```

However if our Webapp is deployed in Kubernetes or OpenShift: We can keep our application in HTTP and use Kubernetes ingress ([spec.tls](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)) or OpenShift route ([spec.tls](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/rest_api/network_apis/route-route-openshift-io-v1.html#specification)) to expose the app in HTTP**s** and route to a service and then a pod in HTTP.

What would be the pros and cons of the 2 solutions?

Can I consider traffic is encrypted inside the cluster (like pod to pod) when using Kubernetes services IP/pods IPs though we are in HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes is often used for apps that is composed of multiple services, e.g. *microservice architecture*. In such architecture, the https-connection to the "app" is terminated at the gateway, typically Kubernetes Ingress load balancer, and then depending on what url the request has, it is forwarded to the appropriated Pod within the cluster.

The case you describe is only a single Pod / Deployment. For so small use cases, it is probably not worth using a full Kubernetes cluster. Kuberntes is typically used for larger environments when you have many nodes to handle your workload.

A benefit with using Kubernetes in a larger environment is that it is very good on separating *infrastructure* from the *applications*. See e.g. [DevOps Before and After Kubernetes](https://thenewstack.io/devops-before-and-after-kubernetes/). As an example, the developers of your app can focus on implementing features and let the infrastructure handle the rest. In your case, this means that the developer does not need to handle the SSL-certificates like `privkey.pem` and `fullchain.pem` - this can instead be handled outside the app and changed independently.

> Can I consider traffic is encrypted inside the cluster (like pod to pod) when using Kubernetes services IP/pods IPs though we are in HTTP?

Pod to Pod traffic is not encrypted unless you or your cluster has configuration for SSL / HTTPS. But Pod to Pod traffic is internal traffic within the Kubernetes cluster and it is typically within a private IP-subnet. That said, you can add a *service mesh* product like e.g. [Istio](https://istio.io/) to get strong encryption for Pod to Pod using *mTLS*, also including authentication with certificates - but this is still managed by the *infrastructure* outside the app-container.